# ios. Disable everyday notification if it is already irrelevant

Tags: ios, notifications, push, local

I want to remind user to take photo everyday. I use code for every day local push notificatons

```
UILocalNotification *everyDayNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
everyDayNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

int hour = [hours_string intValue];
int minutes = [minutes_string intValue];

[components setHour:hour];
[components setMinute:minutes];

NSDate *today10am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

everyDayNotification.fireDate = today10am;
everyDayNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

everyDayNotification.alertBody = @"It us time";
everyDayNotification.alertAction = @"Action";
everyDayNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
everyDayNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"EveryDay"
                                                     forKey:@"RemindNotificaion"];
everyDayNotification.userInfo = userDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:everyDayNotification];
```

But if the user has made the photo before it is time to notice that. I want to skip the notification for today. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making an individual UILocalNotification for each day and storing them, perhaps in an array in NSUserDefaults. Then you can cancel a notification with the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notficiationInstance];
```